# Most efficient way to make predictions on large data?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to write a prediction function that predicts on large text data (so it has to be by batch). But the predict function is a bit slow. So I wonder what can I do to improve its time.

What I have so far:

```py
def get_embeddings(model, data_loader, device):
    
    model.eval()  # eval mode
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        embeddings = torch.tensor([], dtype=torch.float64, device=device)  #initialize empty tensor
        for _, d in enumerate(tqdm(data_loader), 0):
            # model inputs
            input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
            attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)

            # model outputs
            embeddings = torch.cat((embeddings, model.predict(
                input_ids,
                attention_mask=attention_mask
            )))  # concat predictions

    return embeddings.cpu().numpy()  # convert to numpy array
```

I think converting from GPU to CPU takes time so I decided to initialize an empty tensor first and concat all the predictions. Then convert it back to numpy array at the very end. But I am unsure if tensor concatenation will actually be slower.

So I am wondering if there's any better or best practices when it comes to prediction.

Answer (score 0):

A few things caught my attention in your code:

- You are using `float64`. GPUs are considerably slower with it than `float32` and `float16`.
- You might be forcing a conversion from `float32` to `float64`, which can be slow too.
- You are copying the attention mask to the GPU for every input. Instead, create and/or keep it there.
- Make sure all your operations are done in batches to use the full parallelism of the GPU.
- Concatenating is probably useless: GPU->CPU transfers are mostly bandwidth-limited, so it doesn't matter much if it's one big tensor or many small ones (up to a point). Secondly, allocations (caused by `cat`) can be slow.

Comment: For point 4, my data_loader is a dataloader object so it should already be done in batches. For point 3, can you be more explicit?

Comment: @Thomas insert this line: `print(input_ids.shape, input_ids.dtype, attention_mask.shape, attention_mask.dtype)`. What does it say in your intended use case?